# How can I prevent my form from being submitted?

Tags: javascript, html

**I want the form to not be submitted when the inputs are wrong. The error messages do appear but my form still gets submitted nonetheless. I cant seem to find the problem** would appreciate the help thank you :)-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<form action="/handleServer.php" method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <!-- starting with first name-->
        <h4 class="heading" >First name:</h4>
        <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" size="30">
        <span id="errorName" class="error"></span>
        
        <!-- module code -->
        <h4 class="heading">Module code:</h4>
        <input id="mcode" type="text" name="mcode" size="30">   
        <span id="errorCode" class="error"></span>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
<script>
//input field using if-else statements 
function validateForm() {
var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value; 
var mcode = document.getElementById("mcode").value;
var errorN = document.getElementById("errorName"); 
var errorC = document.getElementById("errorCode"); 

//test for an empty input 

if (fname === '' && mcode === '') {
    errorN.innerHTML = "Please fill in the blank";
    errorC.innerHTML = "Please fill in the blank";
    return false; 
}

if (fname === '') {
    errorN.innerHTML = "Please fill in the blank"; 
    return false; 
} else {
    errorN.innerHTML = ""; 
}

if (mcode === '') {
    errorC.innerHTML = "Please fill in the blank";
    return false; 
} else {
    errorC.innerHTML = "";
}

//test for invalid format
if (/^[A-Z]\D{2,30}$/.test(fname) == false) //if its true, it will go to the second input 
{
    errorN.innerHTML = "One capital letter and no digits allowed";
    fname.style.color="red"; 
    return false; 
    
} else {
    fname.innerHTML = "";
}
 
if (/^[a-z]{3}[1-9]\d{4}$/.test(mcode) == false)
{
    errorC.innerHTML = "Wrong format"; 
    mcode.style.color="red"; 
    return false; 
    
} else {
    mcode.innerHTML = ""; 
} 

return true; }
```

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Comment: Hi sorry i thnk i may have phrased my question wrongly, my form actually gets redicrected when the input values are wrong @SridharChidurala

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be these four lines of code:

```js
fname.style.color="red";

fname.innerHTML = "";

mname.style.color="red";

mname.innerHTML = "";
```

`fname` and `mname` are strings, therfore `fname.style` and `mname.style` both result in `undefined`. Obviously you can't set properties on `undefined` which is why you are getting an error.

```js
//You are getting the value properties which are strings:
var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var mcode = document.getElementById("mcode").value;
```

The error is stopping your code before you can return `false`, preventing the cancelation of the form submit.

The solution is to instead make two more variables storing the actual input elements:

```js
var finput = document.getElementById("fname");
var minput = document.getElementById("mname");
```

Then change lines:

```js
fname.style.color="red";

fname.innerHTML = "";

mname.style.color="red";

mname.innerHTML = "";
```

to:

```js
finput.style.color="red";

finput.innerHTML = "";

minput.style.color="red";

minput.innerHTML = "";
```

Here is a working version:

```html
<form action="/handleServer.php" method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <!-- starting with first name-->
  <h4 class="heading">First name:</h4>
  <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" size="30">
  <span id="errorName" class="error"></span>

  <!-- module code -->
  <h4 class="heading">Module code:</h4>
  <input id="mcode" type="text" name="mcode" size="30">
  <span id="errorCode" class="error"></span>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
  //input field using if-else statements 
  function validateForm() {
    var finput = document.getElementById("fname");
    var minput = document.getElementById("mname");
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var mcode = document.getElementById("mcode").value;
    var errorN = document.getElementById("errorName");
    var errorC = document.getElementById("errorCode");

    //test for an empty input 

    if (fname === '' && mcode === '') {
      errorN.innerHTML = "Please fill in the blank";
      errorC.innerHTML = "Please fill in the blank";
      return false;
    }

    if (fname === '') {
      errorN.innerHTML = "Please fill in the blank";
      return false;
    } else {
      errorN.innerHTML = "";
    }

    if (mcode === '') {
      errorC.innerHTML = "Please fill in the blank";
      return false;
    } else {
      errorC.innerHTML = "";
    }

    //test for invalid format
    if (/^[A-Z]\D{2,30}$/.test(fname) == false) //if its true, it will go to the second input 
    {
      errorN.innerHTML = "One capital letter and no digits allowed";
      finput.style.color = "red";
      return false;

    } else {
      finput.innerHTML = "";
    }

    if (/^[a-z]{3}[1-9]\d{4}$/.test(mcode) == false) {
      errorC.innerHTML = "Wrong format";
      minput.style.color = "red";
      return false;

    } else {
      minput.innerHTML = "";
    }

    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: yeh is not suppose to redirect if the two inputs are wrong :(

Comment: @HelpAGirlOut I have fixed my answer and it works how you want now I think.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `event` to the form validation function

```
onsubmit="return validateForm(e)"
```

Then prevent default submission using

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: If you are returning false with the validation function this is not reqired as the redirect will already be canceled.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement should be inside a condition. Right now you're existing the condition and ending the function with a `return true;` regardless of what the conditional statements have already returned. So:

```
if (fname === '' && mcode === '') {
    errorN.innerHTML = "Please fill in the blank";
    errorC.innerHTML = "Please fill in the blank";
    return false; 
}else{
    return true; // THIS IS WHERE YOU NEED TO RETURN TRUE
}
```

I see you're returning false in multiple if statements. You'll need to find a way to unify the conditions so that you have one return only for for either true or false.